# BCP Permissions Error When Using queryout with SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database, bcp

I'm trying to query data from one `database1..table` and import it to another `database2..table`. `database2..table` already has some of the data, so I need to filter it. I'm calling this command:

`bcp "SELECT * FROM Foo.dbo.Bar WHERE id > 10000" queryout ./Bar.txt -N -U user@machine -S tcp:hash.database.windows.net -P password`

`Error: SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 4060
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot open database "master" requested by the login. The
login failed.`

Since user@machine doesn't have access to the `master` database, the query fails. Note that if I use `bcp Foo.dbo.Bar out ./Bar.txt...` instead of the above, it works, since it never tries to open the `master` database.

It's a SQL Azure instance, so I cannot link the servers together.

So: how can I do this filter on data freshness in `Foo.dbo.Bar` without BCP ever trying to connect to `master`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621784.aspx#bcp), you must specify the -d parameter when using queryout with SQL Azure.